# JavaFX multiple scene opening, duplicating of scene

Tags: javafx

I want to have a login page (which I have working), that then goes to a new scene (which I dont have working yet).

I then want this scene to have items that you can click on.  And each item opens another scene/window.  But you can open as many as you want.  They contain different data, but same fxml/scene.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It would require you to create a controller for the scene, and then create a new instantiation of that controller object for each new instance of that scene. I think it will also require passing it a new stage each time.

**EDIT:** **Failing to create a new controller instance for each new instance of a scene would mean it is possible to overwrite data in an open scene in one window from an open scene in another window.**

In case you're newer to JavaFX, I'll provide some examples of creating new views. This question is mostly related to methods of going about doing so.

Assuming you're following MVC pattern, your project may be structured similar to this:

**EDIT: Corrected improper usage of FXMLLoader**

MainApp.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import Controller.LoginController;

public class Main
        extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/View/Login.fxml"));
            Parent     root   = loader.load();

            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

            LoginController loginController = loader.getController();

            // Pass this stage by calling the controller's stage setter.
            // Conversely we could call a singleton class here to
            // give us a stage object that we can re-use many times 
            loginController.setStage(stage);

            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);

            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Resources/icon.png"));
            stage.setTitle("");

            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stage.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

LoginController.java

```
import java.net.URL;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import Controller.MainController;

public class LoginController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;
    private Stage stage;

    public LoginController() {}

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    
        loginButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            doLogin();
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void doLogin() {
    
        // handle login
        
        showMainApplicationView();
    
    }

    @FXML
    private void showMainApplicationView() {
        
        try {

        loader = new FXMLLoader(LoginController.class.getResource("View/mainView.fxml"));

        Parent         root           = (Parent) loader.load();
        MainController mainController = new MainController();

        loader.setController(mainController);

        mainController.setStage(new Stage());

        stage.initModality(m);
        stage.setResizable(isResizable);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Resources/icon.png"));
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        return stage;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // exception handling

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    
        this.stage = stage;

    }

}
```

MainController.java

```
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoginController implements Initializable
{

    public LoginController() {}

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {}


    @FXML
    private void showSubview() {
        /* Same code as the prior examples for launching a new view
         * It will work for creating as many new "windows" of the same
         * view as you desire. If you need to pass different types of
         * data to each view you can use a DAO model, or some kind of
         * "Instance" object that works for sending/receiving data to/from
         * the subview from this class.
         */

    }

    @FXML
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    
        this.stage = stage;

    }

}
```

If you want to reuse a stage more than once and at varying depths into subviews I would recommend using a Singleton class.

StageHolder.java

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final StageHolder
{
    private Stage stage;
    
    private final static StageHolder INSTANCE = new StageHolder();

    private StageHolder() {}

    public static StageHolder getInstance() {

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {

        return this.stage;
    }

    // you can omit this setter if you only want to re-use a single stage over and over.
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {

        this.stage = stage;

    }
}
```

Comment: I followed this to a t.  I can get the login page to show.  But when I click the button.  It crashes with the error.  "Can't extract module name from jdbc-3.0.8.pom: Only outputDirectories and jars are accepted on the path"

Comment: I have this FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("login.fxml")); instead of what you provided, because what you provided gives me an error of "No suitable contrsuctor found for FXMLLoader(String)"

Comment: I get the error "Can't extract module name from jdbc-3.0.8.pom: Only outputDirectories and jars are accepted on the path".  But if I include fx:controller="com.mycompany.btrade.LoginController" in the FXML file, then it works.  BUT....then the loginController I instantiate in your example isnt use.  And its a fresh one tied to the FXML, which then makes the setStage, not pass to the correct Controller

Comment: @Kylie how about clarifying the question as to what you _really_ want and providing [mcve] of what you tried and how it doesn't work as expected (vs. let potential helpers play guessing games and rejecting the guesses ;)

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you're on the nail of what I want.  Its just that when I tried it, it didn't work due to probably issues between our versions of things.   I'll figure it out though, your answer has provided me the path.